# foreach con dos variables php

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach

Tengo el siguiente código en html, se compone de cuatro parejas de input tipo text, donde el usuario puede llenar los grupos necesarios:

HTML:

```
             <div class="form-group">
              <label for="respuesta">Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="respuesta[]" placeholder="respuesta" id="respuesta1" class="form-control">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="resplant">Plantilla Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="resplant[]" placeholder="plantilla respuesta" id="resplant1" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="respuesta">Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="respuesta[]" placeholder="respuesta" id="respuesta2" class="form-control">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="resplant">Plantilla Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="resplant[]" placeholder="plantilla respuesta" id="resplant2" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="respuesta">Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="respuesta[]" placeholder="respuesta" id="respuesta3" class="form-control">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="resplant">Plantilla Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="resplant[]" placeholder="plantilla respuesta" id="resplant3" class="form-control">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="respuesta">Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="respuesta[]" placeholder="respuesta" id="respuesta4" class="form-control">
            </div>
        
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="resplant">Plantilla Respuesta<span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
              <input type="text" name="resplant[]" placeholder="plantilla respuesta" id="resplant4" class="form-control">
            </div>
```

PHP:

```php
    foreach(array_combine($resplant, $respuesta ) as $rplant => $resp ) {        
        $stmt = $conexionwp->prepare("insert into $newplant
        (plantilla, respuesta, negocio)
        values
        (?, ?, ?)")or die($conexionwp->error);
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $rplant, $resp, $negocio);
        $stmt->execute();
     }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy usando un form para enviar datos a un archivo php externo. Solo se diligencia respuesta1 y resplant1

Se supone que solo debería insertar una fila, pero inserta una segunda.

Comment: Verifica lo que tienes en tu bucle, poniendo por ejemplo: `var_dump(array_combine($resplant, $respuesta ));` Por otra parte, no queda claro lo que quieres hacer, por qué combinas esos dos elementos o por qué los declaras como array en el formulario ¿?

Comment: A. Cedano Los declaro como array por que son elementos con un mismo name, al ser parejas (name="respuesta" y name="resplant"), se van a php como dos variables para un mismo insert

Comment: No queda claro qué es lo que quieres hacer con esto, pero intuyo que el principal problema aquí podría ser un error de diseño. Si, como dice @Marcos, algunos datos llegan vacíos o al combinarlos se crean vacíos o dispares, debería inquietarte eso y resolverlo de otra forma, de modo que los datos no lleguen vacíos o dispares. Yo intento siempre ir más allá, no detenerme sólo en un problema causado por un error de diseño, como puede ser el caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano tiene razón. No está claro que debería suceder antes los distintos escenarios y por tal motivo no se puede proponer una solución. Como verás en mi respuesta no propongo una solución ya que en tu pregunta tampoco la estas solicitando. Solo me limito a explicar el porque.

Comment: @Marcos  ¿Cómo puedo enviar estas parejas de input a un php para insertar en una tabla Mysql, teniendo en cuenta que cada pareja va en una fila de la tabla de datos respectivamente es decir, si el usuario diligencia una pareja será igual a una fila, si diligencia dos parejas serán dos filas en la tabla y etc....? La forma mas fácil seria que el usuario realizara una operación por cada pareja, pero quiero que pueda guardar dos, tres o cuatro parejas en una sola operación si así lo necesita.

Comment: @Arjona, entonces ¿necesitarías validar que, por ejemplo, si pusieron algo en `respuestaX` entonces haya algo en `resplantX`? ¿que debería pasar si falla la validación? ¿debería guardarse lo que es válido o todo o nada? Desde ya, me inclino a pensar que no deberías usar `array_combine`.

Comment: Quizá sería más simple si usas checkbox o radiobutton para las respuestas.

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que al guardar los campos (*que son 4 de cada uno*) van a generar dos variables y cada una será un arreglo de 4 posiciones.

Al completar solo el primer grupo vas a obtener algo así:

```php
$respuesta = array ( 0 => 'si', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', )
$resplant = array ( 0 => 'sipi', 1 => '', 2 => '', 3 => '', )
```

Y dado que utilizas `array_combine` para generar la matriz asociativa, vas a obtener como resultado:

```
$resultado = array ( 'sipi' => 'si', '' => '', )
```

¿Por qué?

> [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-combine.php)  — Crea un nuevo array, usando una matriz para las claves y otra para sus valores

Si te fijas, en `$resplant` tenes 2 claves únicas (`'sipi', ''`) y es por esto que obtenes un arreglo con dos posiciones.